# How to use $this->session->set_userdata and $this->session->userdata('adminId') in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, session, upgrade, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to upgrade codeigniter 3 to codeigniter 4. How can I use `$this->session->set_userdata` and `$this->session->userdata('adminId')` in CI 4? I'm a beginner in codeigniter can anyone help?

Comment: just follow: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base on Codeigniter documentation, you can deal session data with session function.

To Retrieving Session Data :

```
session()->get('adminId');
```

and to Set Session Data :

```
session()->set('adminId', $value);
```